# Google CardDAV for Contacts - Read Only?

Tags: iphone, google-contacts-api, mdm, carddav

I'm looking to use Google CardDAV to push a set of Contacts tied to a specific Google account out to a bunch of iPhone devices using our MDM software. So far everything works - i pointed the software to https://google.com/carddav/v1/principals/mygoogleaccount and the contacts all populate down to the iPhones. But - any change that any user makes to the contact list will be reflected back to the Google account,  meaning it will affect all users. Is there a way to make this functionality read only? Maybe create another account that only has read access to the list and push that to the devices instead of using the main credentials? I could probably disable the ability to edit the contacts on the device level, but I don't want to do this, as employees may wish to add their own personal contacts to their individual devices.  I just want the master CardDAV list we are pushing out to stay consistent.

Does anyone have experience or any idea how I would accomplish this?

The above pretty much states it all. Looking to deploy a Contact list to a group of iPhones thru an MDM via Google CardDAV, but need the list to remain read-only at the device level. The Internet does not seem to have any information on how to do this.